# Double line integral of a feynman propagator

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

I'm having trouble in finding the result of the following double integral of a Feynman propagator in Euclidean signature:
\begin{equation}
I = -\frac{i}{(2\pi)^2}\oint_\gamma dx \oint_\gamma dy\,\frac{1}{(x-y)^2}. \tag{1}
\end{equation}
The integrals are on the same contour (a loop only on spatial directions), and $(x-y)^2=(x^0-y^0)^2+(x^1-y^1)^2+(x^2-y^2)^2+(x^3-y^3)^2$. I tried to do these integrals by making the replacement:
\begin{equation}
\oint dy \,\frac{1}{(x-y)^2}\leadsto \int d^4w \oint dy\,\frac{\delta^{(4)}(y-w)}{(x-w)^2}.
\end{equation}
But I ended up with
\begin{equation}
I = -\frac{1}{4\pi} \oint dx \oint dy\,\frac{\delta(|\vec{x}-\vec{y}|)}{|\vec{x}-\vec{y}|},
\end{equation}
wich seems not to be well behaved. When the loop extends into the temporal direction by a length $T$ such that $T \gg R$ (where $R$ is the spatial extent of the loop), the following result is found:
\begin{equation}
I \simeq -\frac{1}{4\pi R}T.
\end{equation}
I couldn't find any resources on the internet about how to deal with (1) when the loop is purely spatial, so I'm really stuck on this problem.

Comment: By spatial contour, do you mean that the contour is on the same time slice for some foliation i.e. $(x^0-y^0)^2=0$ ? I ask because the signature is a little confusing and being able to ignore time altogether would simplify things.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Yes, this is exactly what I meant.